# CEP Dashboard - Visualizing points in Geo Map gadget

Tags: wso2, dashboard, complex-event-processing, wso2-cep

I have an output stream which has lat-long points with a set of other attributes. When I output the same stream as a table gadget I get below data (screen shot). But when I use the same stream for a Geo Map gadget, it doesn't visualize the points or anything. I am using the default dashboard that comes with CEP and not the GeoDashboard.

data in the table gadget image

[image: data in the table gadget image]

Configurations that I provided for Geo Map gadget

geo map configuration image

[image: geo map configuration image]

Am I doing wrong creating this gadget ?

Answer (score 1):

There was an bug with the current js code when using the ui publisher. I have fixed that in the following pull request.
[https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/pull/330](https://github.com/ramindu90/carbon-analytics-common/blob/992e7657b78e74ff33b6f8eb0f53f2c07eb633ef/features/analytics-gadget-templates/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.gadget.chart.template.feature/src/main/charts/geo-map/api.js)

You can get the working file code [here](https://github.com/ramindu90/carbon-analytics-common/blob/992e7657b78e74ff33b6f8eb0f53f2c07eb633ef/features/analytics-gadget-templates/org.wso2.carbon.analytics.gadget.chart.template.feature/src/main/charts/geo-map/api.js).

You will have to replace the code content in
*{CEP_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/extensions/chart-templates/geo-map/api.js*

And generate the gadget again.

Best Regards,
Ramindu.